# 13.10 Fully installed reset and operating system does not boot

Tags: system-installation

My system boots and searches for my operating system and nothing happens. I can run it from a CD just fine. I have tried loading it twice and once on a clean hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

That is some very basic information. I would like to help you but I need some information.

1. What hardware are you running?
2. Did you try to enter the bios and run hardware tests?
3. Also this could be a problem with the boot loader.
4. I mentioned Bios but do you have UEFI instead? If so try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

I hope this helps, best I could do with the information you provided.